# Preventing untrusted_app from accessing database

Tags: android, selinux

I am running on Android 4.4.4 and have two processes. The security context of both the processes are :-

```
com.example.contentproviderexample having security context -->  u:r:hm_phonebookaccess_app:s0  
com.example.contentprovideruser having security context --> u:r:untrusted_app:s0
```

com.example.contentproviderexample is a content provider and the database which has security context as -

```
mydb --> u:object_r:hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:s0 
mydb-journal --> u:object_r:hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:s0
```

The above security context has been set using following rule -

```
type hm_phonebookaccess_app, domain;
app_domain(hm_phonebookaccess_app)
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app dalvikcache_data_file:file { write  setattr };
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:file { read getattr open };
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:dir setattr;
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app zygote:unix_stream_socket { getopt getattr };
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app apk_data_file:dir getattr;
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:dir { write create add_name };
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:file { write create setattr };
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:dir search;
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:dir { read open };
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:file lock;
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:dir remove_name;
allow hm_phonebookaccess_app hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:file unlink;
allow installd hm_phonebookaccess_data_file:lnk_file create;
```

At run time, I am making setenforce as 1.

My aim is to prevent any process which belongs to     domain-->untrusted_app from accessing the database which belongs to the domain-u:r:hm_phonebookaccess_app:s0

NOTE: The content provider is exported as true.

In the seapp_contexts, following entry has been made :-

```
user=_app domain=hm_phonebookaccess_app    name=com.example.contentproviderexample  type=hm_phonebookaccess_data_file
```

My observation is that in enforcement mode, the process "com.example.contentprovideruser" is able to access the database.

Is there any way I can prevent "untrusted_app" domain from accessing that database?

Thanks and Regards,
Souvik

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) have you confirmed that the `sepolicy` binary on the running device reflects your new domain and rules as above? To check for sure, I recommend puling it from the running device with `adb` and loading it into `apol` on your dev box. 2) have you tried introducing a `neverallow` into your type enforcement rules? During compilation, this will cause an error and stop if there are inconsistencies in the policy. On an error, it should help you locate the `allow` rule that is allowing `untrusted_app` to access `hm_phonebookaccess_app`.

Answer (score 0):

This user hit the SE Android mailing list where the question was answered in full. The issue, they failed to describe here, was that they had a web socket dishing up the database and the untrusted_app was accessing it via this web interface. Its important to note that to block open, read, and other raw file io accesses to that database that a direct syscall from the other (source process) process must occur on the database directly (target file). From the kernel's perspective its able to see that untrusted_app is trying to open/read/write a file of type hm_phonebookaccess_data_file.

However, (i'm simplifying here) with the web-interface the kernel sees untrusted_app using a network socket, followed by hm_phonebook reading the database and writing to the socket, this is all OK.

The way to protect sockets with SE Linux is via labeled networking, however, we consider this "unsupported" on AOSP as no convince mechanisms to do so exist.

http://www.mail-archive.com/seandroid-list%40tycho.nsa.gov/msg02073.html

In modern releases of SE Android, one will not be able to simple specify name= name in seapp_contexts as it will result in a build error. It is generally considered unsafe when **NOT** specifying seinfo; seinfo + name is safe.